# Restricition by Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, visual-studio-2012, desktop-application

I want to make a test conducting desktop application and I want to restrict the user to be unable to open any other application once the test is started.

Is there any way or method through which once test is started, the user can not move to any other application or start any other application for that particular time.

If, Yes, what are the things that needs to be restricted.

Comment: There are many factors we need more details, Do you control the machine and is that machine on a domain or is the test run on any end users machine?

Comment: Why don't you just tell the user not to open another application during the test? Assuming that the users intent is to sabotage the test and hence the need to restrict him seems to be a flaw in the test strategy itself. Or is the test about the user reaction when facing an untold restriction of the desktop?

Comment: its on a desktop application!!!

Comment: what if the user doesnt listen to us and open other application!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but here's a bit of info. Blocking of process creation in a legal way is possible by writing a small device driver. This driver can place a hook on process creation through the driver API [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course you would have to implement another driver interface to control when it should start blocking process creation and when to stop doing so. This can be done through what is called driver IoCtls.

WinDDK has plenty of sample code to leverage on, in case you want to pursue this path.

HTH.